# Android abstract activity for layout

Tags: android, android-layout

is it possible to have an abstract activity which defines the layout (navigation and so on) and a subclasses that define content of the activity? How about xml layout files?

I mean I have an xml

```
 <xxx.DefaultNavigationDrawer xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- Fragment contents go in here -->

</FrameLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer_list"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/calendar"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@color/calendar_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp" />

</xxx.DefaultNavigationDrawer>
```

and I'd like all my activities to have such layout. The only thing which would change is marked.

Answer (score 1):

You can set your layout in your base `Activity` class and then in your derived Activity's `onCreate` you can call `FragmentManager.replace()` to replace the contents of your `FrameLayout` with your fragment.

Comment: Do I have to use Fragments?

Comment: Since you want to insert a fragment how can you avoid using fragments then?

Comment: What I'm asking is whether there is another way :). Your answer is perfectly okay.